# Buscar registros inexistentes dentro da mesma tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird

tenho uma tabela contendo informações de usuários. nela contem um campo chamado competência. E quando eu quero puxar uma informação de algum usuário eu puxo pela competência assim:

```
SELECT * FROM registro WHERE competencia = '01/2019'
```

Quero fazer o seguinte: 
Buscar todas as informações que existem na competência '01/2019' mas não existem na competência '02/2019'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só utilizar um subselect verificando a existência:

```
SELECT * FROM registro WHERE competencia = '01/2019' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM registro WHERE competencia = '02/2019')
```

O comando acima tem um erro.

Você precisa verificar a existência ou não para o mesmo usuário e portanto precisa correlacionar as queries:

```
SELECT * FROM registro r1 WHERE competencia = '01/2019' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM registro r2 WHERE r1.usuario = r2.usuario AND competencia = '02/2019')
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode amarrar pela **chave primaria** e usar o operador `NOT IN`

Exemplo:

```
SELECT r.Id FROM registro r
  WHERE 
    competencia = '01/2019' 
    AND r.id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM registro WHERE competencia = '02/2019' and Id = r.id)
```